# Schtasks que no funciona en Windows 10

Tags: windows10

Estoy tratando de crear una tarea en Windows 10 desde un archivo batch usando Schtasks con el parámetro /NP y /RL, del siguiente modo:

```
schtasks /create /tn "Tareax" /tr "c:\pruebabkp\bkp_data.bat" /sc weekly /mo 1 /d MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI /ST 12:00 /RI 10 /DU 9:00 /RL HIGHEST /NP
```

Pero obtengo el mensaje de error "Acceso Denegado".

He tratado de usar el parámetro /RU con todo tipo de cuentas pero obtengo el mismo mensaje. El usuario desde el que estoy corriendo el batch no es la cuenta administrador pero tiene privilegios de administración.

Funciona en Windows 7 , pero en W10 no!

Cualquier ayuda... se agradece!

Comment: Es muy probable que sea cuestión de privilegios, intenta ejecutar como admin.